# Error on Installation of MVC3 at Windows 7 -32 Bit Operating System

Tags: windows-7, asp.net-mvc-3, web-platform-installer

I want to run MVC 3 on my Windows 7 32 Bit machine. I have Visual Studio 2010 and I can create ASP.NET MVC2 projects there. But now, I want to install MVC 3 in my machine. So,
I tried the online installation using Web Platform Installer from http://www.asp.net/mvc/mvc3 link. After installation, I didn't find the ASP.NET MVC 3 Web Project Template in my Visual Studio 2010 Project Templates.
So I again downloaded the Offline Installer from same link. But I got error when I ran the installer. Clicking on the Log file I got:

```
OS Version = 6.1.7600, Platform 2
OS Description = Windows 7 - x86 Ultimate Edition 
CommandLine = h:\temp\ext6142\setup.exe
Using Simultaneous Download and Install mechanism
Operation: Installing
Package Name = Microsoft ASP.NET MVC 3
Package Version = 3.0.11209.0
User Experience Data Collection Policy: Disabled
Number of applicable items: 6
Exe (h:\temp\ext6142\VS10-KB2465236-x86.exe) succeeded.
MSI (h:\temp\ext6142\AspNetWebPages.msi) Installation failed. Msi Log: Microsoft ASP.NET MVC 3_20110118_142652087-MSI_AspNetWebPages.msi.txt
Final Result: Installation failed with error code: (0x80070643), "Fatal error during installation. " (Elapsed time: 0 00:01:39).
```

Comment: Did you install the last MVC3 (final) ? http://www.asp.net/mvc/mvc3 Did you try to do a Windows Update before installation ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After installing from web platform, **I didn't check the selected .NET Framework Version** in Visual Studio Project Template when I wanted to create a new project in MVC 3. **Default .NET Framework was 3.5** in the visual studio of my machine. So **MVC 3 project template wasn't showing** in the project templates. 
And, without uninstalling the existing MVC 3, when I again wanted to install MVC 3 from offline installer, I got the **error** I mentioned in my question. It **may happened because either performing same installation or the file was corrupted** at the time of downloading or any other issue.
Later, after uninstalling MVC 3 from control panel, I again run the web platform installer to install the MVC 3 and this time I check the selected .NET version.  I selected **.NET Framework 4 and MVC 3 project template is now appeared**  in visual studio's project templates.

Answer (score 2):

My computer had trouble uninstalling an older MVC3 RC. Fix:

1. Remove the trailing backslash from the following registry keys:

   ```
   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\ASP.NET\4.0.30319.0\Path
   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\ASP.NET\4.0.30319.0\Path
   ```
2. Uninstalled the old version of "Microsoft ASP.NET Web Pages".
3. Add the trailing backslash back to those keys.
4. Install MVC 3.

Full uninstall instructions:
http://drew-prog.blogspot.com/2010/11/how-to-uninstall-microsoft-aspnet-mvc-3.html

Answer (score 0):

In any case it's good idea to download the offline installer. The web one doesn't care about error messages, and just shows success.

In my case it was c# async CTP that was blocking the installation - the offline installer at least told me so:)