# I am having asp.net mvc 3 installation error. 0x80070643

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want to install ASP.Net MVC 3 but it gives me error (0x80070643) and rollback installation.

I had Visual studio 2017 which i uninstalled and now I have only VS 2012.

I have attached screen shot as well.

I tried to install ASP.Net mvc3 with VS2012 repair but it failed there as well.

I tried trailing backslash in regedit keys as well but no success.

Any expert opinion.

[image]

Comment: Take a look for similar issues: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13487443/error-when-installing-asp-net-mvc-3-tools-update), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11091919/cant-install-asp-net-mvc-3) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4722176/error-on-installation-of-mvc3-at-windows-7-32-bit-operating-system/6349020). Probably one of them matches your current issue.

Comment: nope. @TetsuyaYamamoto these are relevant and tried them but no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Error when installing ASP.NET MVC 3 Tools Update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13487443/error-when-installing-asp-net-mvc-3-tools-update)

[Can't Install Asp.net MVC 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11091919/cant-install-asp-net-mvc-3)

[Error on Installation of MVC3 at Windows 7 -32 Bit Operating System](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4722176/error-on-installation-of-mvc3-at-windows-7-32-bit-operating-system/6349020)

IF ABOVE LINKS DOES NOT WORK FOR YOU THEN TRY BELOW; this will always work for you.

I resolved it after doing the following steps;

```
1. copy following directory from your colleague/friend computer to same path on your machine who have properly installed ASP.Net MVC3. C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET
(make sure they have ASP.Net MVC 3 folder inside with assemblies) 

2. reference following dlls from these folder into your mvc project;
System.Web.Mvc from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET MVC 3\Assemblies 
System.Web.WebPages from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET Web Pages\v1.0\Assemblies
System.Web.WebPages.Razor from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET Web Pages\v1.0\Assemblies
System.Web.Helpers from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET Web Pages\v1.0\Assemblies

3. apply  assemblybinding in web.config 

<runtime>
 <assemblyBinding>
 <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="your mvc dll version you need 3.0.0.0 or 3.0.0.1"/> 
      </dependentAssembly>
 </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
```